# What is a less restrictive word for "crucial"?

Tags: synonyms

I'm writing my research proposal and I have the following sentence:

> The excess charge is considered crucial for the membrane penetration process.

I find the word *crucial* too strong and I'm searching for another word which is less strong in that context. I thought about *required* but it doesn't "fit well" with the sentence. Can you think about better word?

Also, I remember that there was a website for synonyms which also had some similar meaning words, but I can't find it. Do you know any of that kind?

Comment: A "thesaurus" is a listing of synonyms for various words. Some online thesauruses can be found at http://thesaurus.com/browse/crucial and http://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/crucial ... If you are using Microsoft Word you can also click near to a word and press Shift+F7 to open a thesaurus.

Comment: @Yotam: Please let us know, what single word you have finally zeroed in on and accepted. Thanks.

Comment: @Kris: I thought this was clear from the answer marked. I choose important.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If *crucial* is a bit too "strong" for OP's purposes, I'd have thought the same would apply to *vital, necessary, essential,* etc., in that they all imply the process simply couldn't take place at all without the charge.

I therefore suggest it's **important**, which admits of the possibility that the process *could* take place without the charge, but by implication it would be less efficient, slower, or something. Personally I would also accept **central** as a "watered down" version of *crucial*, but I think some people would say that's another "vital" word.

Comment: For a non-"vital" connotation, you could also use **recommended**.

Comment: Yes, but that raises questions about who exactly is doing the recommending. I don't know too much about OP's "membrane penetration" (I doubt it's the one that comes to mind for me!), so I don't know if his target audience would or should trust his judgement. I wouldn't trust Apple Corp if they recommended me to only play music purchased from iTunes on my iPod.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: +1 for the insight.

Answer (score 4):

What about [*necessary*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/necessary)?

> **Adjective**
>   **necessary** (*comparative* **more necessary**, *superlative* **most necessary**)
>   1. needed, required

Answer (score 3):

I like **necessary** that RiMMER Ψ suggests, an additional choice could be **essential**.

As for synonyms reference online, dictionaries like Merriam-Webster (http://www.merriam-webster.com/) contain synonyms of the word explained.

Another useful site for synonyms is this one: http://www.synonym.com/

Answer (score 1):

In the context of your sentence, *vital* works well (in the sense of being essential, necessary, or indispensable).

There are many synonym resources online, but I find the [English Synonym Dictionary](http://dico.isc.cnrs.fr/dico/en/search) interesting in its approach.